# Memory leak in replaceAll in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, replace, valgrind, str-replace

I used Valgrind to find memory leaks in my program. The important functions are as follows:

```
char *replaceAll ( const char *string, const char *substr, const char *replacement ){
  char *tok = NULL;
  char *newstr = NULL;
  char *oldstr = NULL;
  char *strhead = NULL;
  // if either substr or replacement is NULL, duplicate string and let caller handle it
  if ( substr == NULL || replacement == NULL ) return strdup (string);
  newstr = strdup (string);
  strhead = newstr;
  while ( (tok = strstr ( strhead, substr )) ) {
    oldstr = newstr;
    newstr = malloc( strlen(oldstr) - strlen(substr) + strlen(replacement) + 1 );
    // failed to alloc mem, free old string and return NULL
    if ( newstr == NULL ){
      free (oldstr);
      return NULL;
    }
    memcpy ( newstr, oldstr, tok - oldstr );
    memcpy ( newstr + (tok - oldstr), replacement, strlen ( replacement ) );
    memcpy ( newstr + (tok - oldstr) + strlen( replacement ), tok + strlen ( substr ), strlen ( oldstr ) - strlen ( substr ) - ( tok - oldstr ) );
    memset ( newstr + strlen ( oldstr ) - strlen ( substr ) + strlen ( replacement ) , 0, 1 );
    // move back head right after the last replacement
    strhead = newstr + (tok - oldstr) + strlen( replacement );

    free (oldstr);
  }
  return newstr;
}
```

and

```
int transformRegex(char **regexS){

    char* retS;
    retS = (char*) malloc(400);
    memset(retS, 0x00, 400);

    retS = replaceAll(*regexS, ".", "\\.");

    if (strstr(*regexS, "*")) {
      retS = replaceAll(retS, "**", "@");
      retS = replaceAll(retS, "*", "[^\\.]ß");
      retS = replaceAll(retS, "ß", "*");
      retS = replaceAll(retS, "@", ".*");
    }

    if(strstr(*regexS, "%")){
      retS = replaceAll(retS, "%", "[^\\.]{1}");
    }

    char tmpStr[strlen(retS)+3];
    memset(tmpStr, 0x00, strlen(retS)+3);
    memcpy(tmpStr, "^", 1);
    memcpy(&tmpStr[1], retS, strlen(retS));
    strcat(tmpStr,  "$");
    memcpy(*regexS, tmpStr, strlen(tmpStr));

    free(retS);

    return 0;
}
```

Now Valgrind reports me

```
==29218== 129 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 9
==29218==    at 0x4C27DD0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==29218==    by 0x400A64: **replaceAll** (regcomptest.c:44)
==29218==    by 0x400C61: **transformRegex** (regcomptest.c:141)
==29218==    by 0x400F9F: main (regcomptest.c:221)
==29218==
==29218== 134 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 9
==29218==    at 0x4C27DD0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==29218==    by 0x400A64: **replaceAll** (regcomptest.c:44)
==29218==    by 0x400C34: **transformRegex** (regcomptest.c:136)
==29218==    by 0x400F9F: main (regcomptest.c:221)
==29218==
==29218== 6,000 bytes in 15 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 9
==29218==    at 0x4C27DD0: **malloc** (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==29218==    by 0x400C07: **transformRegex** (regcomptest.c:132)
==29218==    by 0x400F9F: main (regcomptest.c:221)
```

where record 9 refers to the malloc(400) call. Why is it 400**15*, and why does it leak when I say free(retS)? And how do I implement this correctly so that replaceAll doesn't leak memory? Because transformRegex changes the parameter by Reference, any temporary variables should be freed by the end of the function. But I have no idea how to, my Java past blocks thinking in C ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
retS = (char*) malloc(400);
```

Your never free this part of memory.

`strdup` copy the string use `malloc`. when your free oldstr , you free the memory alloc by `strdup`

You can add `free(string);`after `newstr = strdup (string);`

Or you can use a variable to store the reS . like : `char *reSS = reS ;` just after call malloc. Then you free reSS at the end of main.

Comment: +1.  Note that `retS` also needs to be freed after each call to `replaceAll`

Comment: when I do either (free after each replaceAll or free(string)) I get errors. My idea is to have an auxiliary variable retS which is allocated once and freed in the end. How can I free it -after each replaceAll- if I still need to use it?

Comment: @dasLort You can use a pointer to store the reS . like char * reSS = reS.Then free reSS at last

Comment: @dasLort: `retS = (char*) malloc(400);` simply is useless, as all that is done to the memory allocated, is being set to `0` in the next line (`memset(retS, 0x00, 400)`). Then the value of `retS ` is overwritten and there fore **lost** by this line `retS = replaceAll(*regexS, ".", "\\.");`! The latter line does not copy anthing to the memory referenced by `retS`, but just assigns a new value to the reference itself. The same mistake as in the last question, btw ...